# add status_code next to each row

Tags: r

how to apply a function to a list of df and append result to new column next to row evaluated:

My df has only unidad and urlcols. I need to apply to it:

1.- httr::GET function to each url.
2.- store the result (200, 303, 404) to a new column status_code .

```
df <- structure(list(unidad = c("vd", "vd", "da", "da"), url = c("https://google.com", 
"https://google.com/sdsds", "https://youtube.com", 
"youtefe.com"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 2:5)
```

I've tried:

```
apply(df$url, 1, function(x) httr::GET(x))
```

Returning:

```
Error in apply(df$url, 1, function(x) httr::GET(x)) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

I've also tried:

```
apply(dat$url, 1, function(x) httr::GET(x)$status_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df$new_col <- sapply(df$url, FUN=function(x) httr::GET(x)$status_code)
```

The fourth element doesn't work for me, though. But if I delete the last one ("youtefe.com") and use just the first three it runs fine.

Comment: It was a made up url, that should return some kind of status, right?

Comment: I haven't really worked with urls so I can't really help you there. The error I got was something along the lines of not being able to connect so I think you need real urls. @akrun's answer could be helpful there.

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to have function that returns `NA` when it returns an error - e.g. `tryCatch` or `purrr::possibly`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
fn1 <- function(x) httr::GET(x)$status_code
pfn1 <- possibly(fn1, otherwise = NA_integer_)
df <- df %>%
     mutate(status_code = map_int(url, pfn1))
```

-output

```
  unidad                      url status_code
2     vd       https://google.com         200
3     vd https://google.com/sdsds         404
4     da      https://youtube.com         200
5     da              youtefe.com          NA
```

---

`apply` needs a matrix or data.frame as input i.e. one with `dim` attributes.  The `df$url` is a `vector` which doesn't have dimension attributes